# Connection (if any) between James Baldwin and "Easy Rider"? Why would he be signing a copy circa '60s or '70s?

Tags: identification-request, james-baldwin

I ran across the video [ABC Tried to Bury This James Baldwin Interview. Four Decades Later, It's Blisteringly Relevant.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jXwWCyMJyc) The video's notes begin:

> Buried by ABC at the time, the segment has resurfaced over four decades later, revealing a unique glimpse into Baldwin’s private life—as well as his resounding criticism about white fragility, as blisteringly relevant today as it was **in 1979.**

It shows some file footage of author [James Baldwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Baldwin) at a book signing. I can make out two of the books are [*Another Country* (1962)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_Country_(novel)) and [*Blues for Mr. Charlie* (play, 1964)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blues_for_Mister_Charlie) (images below) but he is also signing a book that appears to be titled *Easy Rider*.

This puzzles me; there is of course the movie of that title from 1969 [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064276/) and apparently [a book about that movie with the same title by Lee Hill](https://www.bookdepository.com/Easy-Rider-Lee-Hill/9780851705439) from 1996 which seems equally irrelevant and decades too late for that file footage.

So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** What is the connection (if any) between James Baldwin and *Easy Rider*? Why would he be signing a copy circa '60s or '70s?

---

[image: James Baldwin signing a copy of Easy Rider?]

[image: James Baldwin signing a copy of Another Country]

[image: Blues for Mr. Charlie (James Baldwin)] [source](https://africa.ufl.edu/achebe-baldwin-at-40-an-online-exhibition/)

[image: James Baldwin signing a copy of "Blues for Mr. Charlie"]

Comment: I'd originally [posted](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/116533/45856) this in Movies SE but then noticed that Literature SE exists so promptly moved it here.

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Hope you'll continue posting interesting questions here - I know you're a heavyweight asker on the network.

Comment: @Randal'Thor ha! I'm simply an SE addict and procrastinator and SE is my distraction of choice :-) *Thank you for the welcome!*

Comment: @Randal'Thor here it goes! https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/22721/15394

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be James Baldwin's own publication [*Easy Rider*, which can be found in WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/easy-rider/oclc/9230939). The notes in the WorldCat entry describe this publication as follows:

> "A selection from James Baldwin's forthcoming novel, *Another country*." --Cover. In *The Dial: an annual of fiction*. New York, 1962. p. 3-26.

Comment: Thank you, that was quick! Wikipedia's [James Baldwin; collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Baldwin#Collections) didn't mention it and that's as far as I'd gotten.

Comment: I have posted a few dozen questions about Wikipedia articles, mostly about claims without sources. Wikipedia is great but far from perfect.