# Help understanding this Arcadia abstract referencing "Ted Chiang’s Story of Your Life (1998) and its filmic adaptation Arrival (2016)"

Tags: meaning, adaptation-comparison, adaptations

Israel Noletto and Sebastião Lopes's June 1, 2019 [Heptapod B and the Paradox of Foreknowledge: Confronting Literature and its Filmic Adaptation](https://doi.org/10.1515/arcadia-2019-0003) in Arcadia is already challenging for me to read and understand. I won't have access to the full paper for a while, but in principle I should be able to at least understand the sentences of the abstract before diving in to the full paper.

> Ted Chiang’s Story of Your Life (1998) and its filmic adaptation Arrival (2016) both use Heptapod B, an artificial language from extra-terrestrial origin, capable of conferring on its speakers the ability of precognition, as a primordial narrative framework. Innovative as it is, it not only determines the way the stories are recounted, but also raises some very interesting philosophical issues. Focusing on that fantastical language, **we promote a comparative analysis of the differing perspectives of the novella writer and the filmmakers regarding the free will and determinism dichotomy in connection with foreknowledge, and how these distinct views may have been influenced by the adaptation process.** With the aim of providing a solid basis for such discussion, we collect and review the contributions of Linda Hutcheon, Brian McFarlane, George Bluestone, Linda Gualda as well as of others in relation to the plot developments in the literary text and its filmic adaptation. As a result, we point out what is prioritized or transformed in the adaptation process, thus offering a theoretical and philosophical criticism on the two stories and a comprehensive exegesis of the texts.

I can apply my subject-verb-object that I learned in school, and I get the following; the authors propose that the views of the filmmakers on "free will and determinism dichotomy" may differ from those of the novella author because those of the filmmakers may have been "influenced by the adaptation process".

Part of my problem is a dissonance between what I expected to see; that the difference in views affected the adaptation process, and what I now believe the abstract discusses; how the process may have affected the views.

**Questions:**

1. Have I got that part right? The authors will explore how the adaptation process may have affected the filmmakers' views on the dichotomy, and not how their views may have affected the adaptation process?
2. Beyond that, what else does this abstract say? Yes, it's written in English and I'm a native speaker, but I am really struggling with what feel to me to be deliberately elaborately-constructed and densely-concepted (new word alert?) sentences.

Comment: help with tagging most welcomed!

Comment: I invite you to read [How do I tag questions properly?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/how-do-i-tag-questions-properly). Not sure if the tags are just right yet but I've added [meaning] as it seems clearly relevant.

Comment: @bobble good reference, thanks! In this particular case it seems "Questions that don’t fall into any of the above categories" applies, but I will continue to check back there in the future. And yes, [meaning] is certainly what my question asks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Journal abstracts have a word limit, and some authors seem to struggle to fit what they want to say into this limit, leading to terse descriptions that are hard to follow. If you suspect that this might have happened, you just have to ignore the abstract and read the body of the paper, where hopefully the authors have enough space to express themselves more clearly.

Moving on to the questions:

1. Yes, you’ve interpreted this correctly. Noletto & Lopes write:

   > Whereas the novella favors a hard deterministic view, Villeneuve and Heisserer attempt to deviate from that in favor of the power of choice. We defend the premise that **the adaptation process** and the medium specificities **had a major impact on this approach**.
   >
   > <sub>Israel A. C. Noletto & Sebastião A. T. Lopes (2019). ‘Heptapod B and the Paradox of Foreknowledge: Confronting Literature and its Filmic Adaptation’. *Arcadia 54*:1, p. 88.</sub>

   By “premise” the authors mean “claim, thesis”; by “this approach” they mean “Villeneuve and Heisserer’s attempt to deviate from a hard deterministic view”; and by “view” they mean the implications of the fictional events of the story (not the actual view of Chiang or the screenwriters).

   The authors’ argument for their thesis is that “the basics of screen writing” are:

   > (1) engagement in the hero’s voyage of discovery; (2) immediate conflict and tension; and (3) emotive impact through choice, and immediate stimulus.
   >
   > <sub>Noletto & Lopes, p. 94.</sub>

   A common plot template for movies is that the hero saves the day through his or her choices, and Noletto & Lopes say that in order to better fit this template, the screenwriters attempted “to change the deterministic character observed in the book into an issue regarding ‘choice’ or the exercise of free will”.
2. I’ll quickly gloss the other parts of the abstract. But as noted above, you really have to read the whole paper.

   > Ted Chiang’s *Story of Your Life* (1998) and its filmic adaptation *Arrival* (2016) both use Heptapod B, an artificial language from extra-terrestrial origin, capable of conferring on its speakers the ability of precognition, as a primordial narrative framework.

   By “primordial” Noletto & Lopes mean “basic, fundamental”, that is, both works use the idea of an alien language that confers precognition (seeing the future) as a basic element of the plot.

   > Innovative as it is, it not only determines the way the stories are recounted,

   Both works make use of the character’s precogition to present the story out of order. By “determine” the authors mean “influence, shape, affect”.

   > but also raises some very interesting philosophical issues.

   The two philosophical issues discussed in the paper are [determinism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/determinism-causal/) versus [free will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/freewill/), and [teleology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology) (the idea that the universe has a purpose).

   > With the aim of providing a solid basis for such discussion, we collect and review the contributions of Linda Hutcheon, Brian McFarlane, George Bluestone, Linda Gualda as well as of others in relation to the plot developments in the literary text and its filmic adaptation.

   Hutcheon, McFarlane, Bluestone, and Gualda are academics who have written about the adaptation of literature into cinema.

   > As a result, we point out what is prioritized or transformed in the adaptation process,

   The paper discusses which elements of Chiang’s story appeared in the movie and which elements of the movie were added or changed in adaptation.

   > thus offering a theoretical and philosophical criticism on the two stories

   The paper discusses the relationship between the two works using the theories of Hutcheon et al. about cinematic adaptation. It discusses the different implications of the two works for the two philosophical ideas noted above.

   > and a comprehensive exegesis of the texts.

   An “exegesis” is an interpretation or explanation.

It might be helpful to have a summary of the jargon employed here:

| Jargon | Gloss |
| --- | --- |
| determine | affect, influence |
| exegesis | explanation, interpretation |
| premise | claim, thesis |
| primordial | basic, fundamental |
| view | implication of a text |

I feel that the jargon uses of “determine”, “premise” and “view” are particularly unhelpful, but every academic field has its own collection of unhelpful jargon, like “dynamic programming” in computer science, or “type I and II errors” in statistics.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I'll finally be getting a copy of the paper today so this is going to be both helpful and timely.